# Why is my php flock not detect an existing lock when running command twice?

Tags: php, symfony, flock, splfileobject

A little explanation, I have a Symfony2 setup. I'm using an abstract command class that I extend. I want any of those batches to be able to run only once. My goal is to make a lock file which I open and flock so that the lock is automatically released when the php script dies in any way possible.

To realize this, I have created a class named Lock. This class extends SplFileObject and is basically a wrapper to create a *.lock somewhere (usually /var/lock/*). Now I have a problem detecting this lock. I did have a setup where it worked using fopen and flock. For some reason it won't detect it any more.

I have created an OOP structure to basically do what I want:

- determine a name for the lock file (uses folders)
- create a Lock object

  - create the directory and lock file if they don't exist
  - call the SplFileObject::__construct()
- lock the file

I can't get this to work with neither the handle nor the spl file object. If I run the script, let it sleep for 15 seconds and run the same script in another console I will get a result that the script managed to lock the file, flock returns true. If I make 2 Lock objects on the same lock file in the same script, I get true on the first lock and false on the second, meaning the second time it failed to obtain the lock. The script seems to work.

However, when I run the script 2 times with 2 locks in both scripts, I get True and false on both scripts... Meaning it seems like it doesn't lock the file properly across scripts :/

Is there someone that can tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've checked the file name and it's equal for both times I run the script. I have tried multiple permissions such as 777, 755, 733 but no difference.

The way I call it (just a part of the class):

```
abstract class AbstractTripolisCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
[...]
  /**
   * Locks the current file based on environments
   *
   * @param string $application_env
   * @param string $symfony_env
   */
  private function lockCommand($application_env, $symfony_env)
  {
    $lock_name  = "tripolis/$application_env/$symfony_env/" . crc32(get_class($this));
    $lock = new Lock($lock_name, 'w+', $this->getContainer()->get('filesystem'));
    var_dump($lock->lock());
    $lock2 = new Lock($lock_name, 'w+', $this->getContainer()->get('filesystem'));
    var_dump($lock2->lock());
    // results when ran 2 times at the same time
    // bool(true)
    // bool(false)
    // when I run this script twice I expect the second run at the same time
    // bool(false)
    // bool(false)

    if(!$lock->lock()) {
      throw new Tripolis\Exception('Unable to obtain lock, script is already running');
    }
  }
[...]
}
```

Lock.php

```
namespace Something\Component\File;

use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;

/**
 * Creates a new SplFileObject with access to lock and release locks
 * Upon creation it will create the lock file if not exists
 *
 * The lock works by keeping a stream open to the lock file instead
 * of creating/deleting the lock file. This way the lock is always
 * released when the script ends or crashes.
 *
 * create a file named /var/lock/something/something.lock
 * <example>
 *   $lock = new Lock('something');
 *   $lock->lock();
 *   $lock->release();
 * </example>
 *
 * create a file named /var/lock/something/my-lock-file.lock
 * <example>
 *   $lock = new Lock('something/my-lock-file');
 *   $lock->lock();
 * </example>
 *
 * NOTE: locks that are not released are released
 * automatically when the php script ends
 *
 * @author Iltar van der Berg <ivanderberg@something.nl>
 */
class Lock extends \SplFileObject implements Lockable
{
  /**
   * @param string     $file_name
   * @param string     $open_mode
   * @param Filesystem $filesystem
   * @param string     $lock_directory
   */
  public function __construct($file_name, $open_mode = 'r+', Filesystem $filesystem = null, $lock_directory = '/var/lock')
  {
    $filesystem = $filesystem ?: new Filesystem();
    $file = self::touchLockFile($file_name, $lock_directory, $filesystem);
    parent::__construct($file, $open_mode);

  }

  /**
   * Returns true if the lock is placed, false if unable to
   *
   * @return boolean
   */
  public function lock()
  {
    return $this->flock(LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB);
  }

  /**
   * Returns true if the lock is released
   *
   * @return bool
   */
  public function release()
  {
    return $this->flock(LOCK_UN);
  }

  /**
   * Attempts to create a lock file for a given filename and directory
   * it will return a string if the file is touched
   *
   * @param  string     $file_name
   * @param  string     $lock_directory
   * @param  Filesystem $filesystem
   * @return string
   */
  private static function touchLockFile($file_name, $lock_directory, Filesystem $filesystem)
  {
    $lock_file_path = explode('/', $file_name);
    $lock_file      = array_pop($lock_file_path);

    $path = "$lock_directory/" . (empty($lock_file_path)
      ? $lock_file
      :  implode('/', $lock_file_path));

    $lock_file = "$path/$lock_file.lock";

    if(!$filesystem->exists($path) || !is_dir($path)) {
      $filesystem->mkdir($path);
    }

    return $lock_file;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your description of the problem is confusing. What does "true and false on both scripts" mean?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @David Check my comment in lockCommand() in the first code block.

Comment: @Jay Ubuntu and CentOS (yes I have checked if /var/lock is compatible on our systems). Edit: my local machine runs Ubuntu to clarify :)

Comment: My bet is that either the lock or the file is being destroyed earlier than you think because the functions that own those objects return, thus making the objects eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: I have had OOM errors because php didn't use it's garbage collection properly but I'll try it.

Comment: Hah, you gotta be kidding me! I have added "return $lock;" and I have assigned that lock somewhere to be stored. It works fine now :/ Yay for the amazing PHP garbage collection -.- Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is that either the lock or the file is being destroyed earlier than you think because the functions that own those objects return, thus making the objects eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: This was the case, I have made lockCommand() return my Lock object and I've stored it somewhere. Because the object is removed as I'm going out of scope with my sleep(15), I won't have the lock anymore. My solution is to store it within the Command class so it won't disappear until my command has exited.